# Footer is not covering 100% of the page's width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width, footer

i have a page with the following footer code

```
.footer {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
color: bisque;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

i know most of people don't use "height: 100%" but i think (not sure) it's not part of the problem, the thing is, it covers 100% of the screen size, but not all elements of my site will cover 100% of the screen size depending on the screen dimension, and it would cause an horizontal overflow, and whenever there's an horizontal overflow, my footer doesn't cover the overflowed parts, causing it to show up some white spaces when i scroll the screen horizontally.

i have some doubts, do i need to program my site on a way that with any screen size it wont overflow horizontally? is it recommended or possible with any site? and also, is there a way for me to make my footer cover overflowed areas too?

heres the full html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sobre nós</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="about_me">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v17.0" nonce="Aw1TIrLL"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-content">
    <img src="img/logo-3.png" class="nav-logo" >
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Página inicial</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Sobre</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="about_me.html" target="_blank" >Sobre mim</a></li>
          <li><a href="about_us.html" target="_blank">Sobre nós</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Serviços</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Começar um projeto</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Limpeza de PC</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="fb-tt-buttons">
      <div class="tt-button">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/sryazigi?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-screen-name="false" data-lang="pt" data-dnt="true" data-show-count="false"></a>
        <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </div>
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100094330637469" data-width="50" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-share=""></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="sandwich-icon" onclick="toggleMenu()">
        &#9776; 
      </div>
      <div class="sandwich-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Página inicial</a></li>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Sobre</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="about_me.html">Sobre mim</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sobre nós</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#">Serviços</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Criação de websites</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Limpeza de PC</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
  </nav>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div class="about-us-container">
  <h2 class="orange"> Yazigi Tech: desde 2023 transformando idéias e sonhos em sistemas rentáveis! </h2>
mais do que um sistema web para seu negócio, a Yazigi Tech batalha para assegurar que o contratante tenha em mãos um site escalável, com uma boa infraestrutura de segurança, e que possa satisfazer todas as expectativas do cliente, nosso foco é na perfeição entre o sistema, e o que o cliente espera que será o sistema, com entrevistas, protótipos, e aprimoração de seu website, pode ter certeza que a Yazigi Tech é a empresa certa para quem busca insights, segurança e rentabilidade em seus negócios.<br>

<h2 class="orange">Garantia com a empresa</h2> após a finalização de seu sistema web, a Yazigi Tech pelo período de 1 mês, prestará auxílio na manutenção do website caso sejam encontrados bugs, problemas no funcionamento e problemas técnicos.<br>

<h2 class="orange">Qualidade na segurança</h2> em nosso sistema todas as senhas de acesso são devidamente criptografadas e a lei de proteção geral de dados (LGPD) é respeitada, nossos sistemas são pensados de maneira à evitar invasões e promover um ambiente seguro.<br>

<h2 class="orange">Preocupação com a qualidade</h2>Aprendizado é o alicerce de nosso sucesso. Em um mundo tecnológico em constante evolução, estamos empenhados em manter nossas equipes atualizadas com as mais recentes tendências e ferramentas. Investimos continuamente em programas de treinamento e desenvolvimento para garantir que nossos desenvolvedores estejam sempre na vanguarda da inovação.<br>

Não estamos apenas focados no crescimento quantitativo. Nosso compromisso é com a qualidade, não apenas em nosso código, mas também em nossos relacionamentos com os clientes. Buscamos entender profundamente as necessidades e desafios de nossos clientes e, em parceria com eles, entregamos soluções que atendem suas expectativas.<br>
<img src="img/happy-it-worker.png">
<a href=#><h3 class="orange"><u> Faça você também parte da nossa história</u></h3></a>

<br><b>Victor Yazigi | Tecnologia e inovação</b>


  </div> 
  
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <div class="footer">
    <img src="img/logo-3.png" alt="Minha logo" class="footer-logo">
    <div class="footer-info">
      Yazigi Tech software e manutenção de computadores<br>
      Editor da página: Victor Yazigi<br>
      Designer da página: Sabrina Leonel
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the full CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;900&display=swap');

html, body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.about_me {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
  justify-content:left;
  width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content-wrapper-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 250px);
}
a {
  color: white;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  z-index: 100;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: black;
}

.nav-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right:3.5rem; /* Increase the padding on the left and right */
}

.nav-logo {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-5%);
  width: 9.375rem;
  height:9.375rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 4rem; /* Add some right margin */
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

nav li {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.sandwich-icon {
  display: none;
}

.sandwich-menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9vh;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 9999999999999;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
 
  .nav-content{
    display: none;
  }

  .sandwich-icon {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: fit-content;
  }

  .sandwich-menu .show-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 10rem;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sandwich-menu .show-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9vh;
    min-height: 3.5rem;
    z-index: 100;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background-color: black;
  }
}

nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  height: 75px;
}

  nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FF7415;
}
  nav .has-submenu {
    position: relative;
  }

  nav .has-submenu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  nav .has-submenu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }

  nav .has-submenu:hover .sub-menu a {
    background-color: black;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  nav .has-submenu .sub-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #FF7415;
  }

  nav ul li {
    position: relative;
  }

  nav ul li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }

  nav .has-submenu:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0.625rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 0.0625rem 0.0625rem 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.1875rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  nav .has-submenu:hover:after {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  }

  .fb-tt-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Set flex-direction to column for vertical alignment */
    align-items: flex-end; /* Align buttons to the right side of the container */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    right: 1%; /* Adjust the right position */
    bottom: 0.5rem;
  }

  .tt-button{
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }

.homepage-text-large {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50.6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 56px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.homepage-text-large .first-line {
  text-transform:none;
}

.homepage-text-large-orange {
  color:#FF7415;
}

.homepage-text-medium {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.homepage-text-small {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 15.7px;
  font-weight: 1;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: none;
}

.computer-boy {
  margin-top: 1%;
  transform: translateX(-13%);
  top: 2%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 547px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  width: fit-content;
}

.home-main-buttons {  
  align-items: center;
  margin-inline:1rem;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #FF7415;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px,rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px,rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 -3px 0 inset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: WHITE;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 11.875rem;
  height: 3.75rem;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: box-shadow .15s,transform .15s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  white-space: nowrap;
  will-change: box-shadow,transform;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.home-main-buttons:focus {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 0 0 1.5px inset, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.4) 0 2px 4px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 -3px 0 inset;
}

.home-main-buttons:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(31, 28, 37, 0.4) 0 4px 8px, rgba(45, 35, 66, 0.3) 0 7px 13px -3px, rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 -3px 0 inset;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.home-main-buttons:active {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 116, 21) 0 3px 7px inset;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.footer {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
color: bisque;
font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-logo {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width:12.5rem;
  height:12.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer-info {
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.white-border-bot {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.white-border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.white-border-sides{
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.pumpkin-orange {
  color:#FF7415;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}

.white-background{
  background-color: white;
}

.computer-hacker {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.about-me-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 250px;
  min-width: 500px;
  top: 9.375rem;
}

.presentation-gif {
  position: relative;
  left: 10rem;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.ability-table {
  position: relative;
  width: 91%;
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  right: 7%;
  left: 2%;
}

.ability-table td{
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.table-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.center-stuff {
  text-align: center;
}

.hello {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  left: 7rem;
  min-width: 345px;
  max-height: 50px;
  top:3.125rem;
}

.certificate-1{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  left: 40px;
}

.certificate-2{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  right: 175px;
}

.flex-container-about-me {
  display: flex;
}

.about-us-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
  right: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  top:5rem;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.orange {
  color:#FF7415;
}
```

I tried to change it several times but it didn't seem to work.
also is there any other responsiveness issue on my code apart from the footer? i'm trying to make it 100%

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100vw;`?

Comment: yes! it stays with the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The page is too wide because `.about-us-container` has a fixed `width` of 1100px and `left` set to 20%, which probably causes it to become too wide unless you have a very large screen.

When elements are wider than the window, their parent element(s) do not become as large as they are. Instead, the parent element will stay at a max of 100% window width. This is why the `<body>` and thus the `<footer>` elements will not grow larger than the window, creating the gap on the right side of the `<footer>`.

All of this shows you that websites are not generally intended to be horizontally scrolled, and it is not recommended behaviour. Don't do it unless there is some specific reason.

You could fix it by having your `.about-us-container` get a `width: auto;` instead of `width: 1100px;`, and `padding-left: 20%;` instead of `left: 20%;`.